# Log File in Batch won't stop updating

Tags: batch-file, logging, time, append

I have a simple problem in my program I cannot seem to find the answer to. I have a file called `Start.Bat`, which gets the username/ date and time and appends it to `LOGS.txt` file. When I run the script it goes to the `logs` file but it never stops appending the date/time so my program gets stuck and won't close. Here is my code.

```
@echo off
cls
echo Date: %date% Time: %time%
echo Username: %username%
start.bat >> C:\scripts\ColWork3\LOGS.txt
exit
```

This is a sample of what my `logs.txt` file gets

```
Date: 18/10/2015 Time: 16:14:13.76
Username: JOEY

Date: 18/10/2015 Time: 16:15:53.68
Username: JOEY

Date: 18/10/2015 Time: 16:15:53.69
Username: JOEY

Date: 18/10/2015 Time: 16:15:53.69
Username: JOEY

Date: 18/10/2015 Time: 16:15:53.69
Username: JOEY
```

So as you can see it just keeps updating every millisecond and won't end my batch file.

How would I get it to display only once so that then my batch file can stop?

Even when I append with only one `>` symbol it only shows one record but keeps updating the same record until I close the command prompt manually.

Comment: What does calling it Recursively mean? And i was instructed to call it Start.Bat, is there any workaround for keeping its name Start.bat

Comment: Well, strictly speaking you can use `start.bat`, it's just uhm well bad practice. As for the recursion, why don't you read the first link for the word on google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call your batch file RECURSIVELY, but you don't need that.
Simply redirect `echo` commands.

```
@echo off
echo Date: %date% Time: %time%>> C:\scripts\ColWork3\LOGS.txt
echo Username: %username%>> C:\scripts\ColWork3\LOGS.txt
```

Or redirect a group of commands:

```
@echo off
(
    echo Date: %date% Time: %time%
    echo Username: %username%
)>> C:\scripts\ColWork3\LOGS.txt
```

P.S. `start` is an internal command name, so it's better to rename it to `launch.bat` for example.

Comment: Thank you so much you fixed my problem. I'm assuming Calling it recursively is what was giving me the problems, I appreciate the help!